# example of a noetherian local rings whose ideals are direct sum of R modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone please give me an example of a Noetherian local rings whose ideals are direct sum of R modules

Comment: What is $R$?${}{}$

Comment: Here R is a commutative noetherian local ring